# Response data in postman different than in terminal or chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting users from twitter by ID, when I res.json the response of the id's i get a set of data, on my browser, but when I do it on postman although I get the same number of results they are different, the difference is that longer id's are getting rounded up or down. In postman they arent.. here is an example

```js
//  in chrome / or console.log in terminal
  
    990122707,
    16667912,
    719066247468429300,
    142583378,
    4825868418,
    4769264472,
    4736618952,
    3915770119, 
    
 // versus in postman
 
   990122707,
    16667912,
    719066247468429313,
    142583378,
    4825868418,
    4769264472,
    4736618952,
    3915770119,
```

Comment: can I add an interceptor to my request headers to convert it to string?

Comment: yes, you need to convert ids from being numbers to become text strings. particular code depends on what framework or middleware you use.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript in Chrome or Terminal? See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids.html

Comment: Yes so I understand that the issue is js itself... when I console.log the data with an interceptor it shows them as strings. So I will make sure to keep them as strings

Comment: right but when you use the endpoint ('1.1/followers/ids.json') the id_str isnt present, when I add an Interceptor to axios and console.log(data) it returns the data as it should be in json as a string, but once it comes for me to edit it still changes it. When I add an interceptor the whole thing is  a string so I cannot use array.map or anything of the sort

Answer (score 0):

Just saw from the documentation that you can add a parameter to stringify_ids